# Is it possible to make a food item that gives you a specified effect after eating in minecraft java?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The title speaks for itself. Im basically trying to make bread that you eat and then you get nausea and poison for 5 secs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to detect a player consuming food items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/312941/is-it-possible-to-detect-a-player-consuming-food-items)

Comment: Its not a straight duplicate, but goes to the same point.