# Testing the age of a certain item in ticks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm developing a Minecraft server which incorporates realism using a command block network in the center of the map. I'm trying to simulate food spoiling via testing for the age of an item (i.e. if a bread item is left in a chest for 5 ingame days then it becomes spoiled). If a player eats such a food, then they will receive the poison effect. Is it possible to do this via commands (without plugins, of course)?

**NB:** One drawback of this is that foodstuffs are stackable, causing each individual item to lose their age property when combined with others. [Asked a question regarding this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/389823/220080)

Comment: To which part of the question are you asking if it is possible? See [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/312941/is-it-possible-to-detect-a-player-consuming-food-items) for applying potion effects for eating certain foods. As for making items unstackable, create custom NBT for each item. When an item is `summon`ed, this can be done with `summon minecraft:item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:dirt",Count:1b,tag:{test:1b}}}`.

Comment: @David What does the `1b` mean?

Comment: @Corsaka 1b refers to `1 byte`, or true. It's just a true or false value.

Comment: @David So isn't it the same every time? Why does it make things unstackable?

Comment: @Corsaka Changing "test" to a different tag will cause the tag to be different. I should have clarified. Different custom nbt tags will make items non-stackable.

Comment: As for the actual question, this would be absurdly complicated. The least intensive solution I can think of would be to have something count up every tick, and when an item is spawned, grab the current timer time, add 5 days, and wait until the timer is equal to that end time, then spoil the item. Zero idea how possible that is especially with command blocks, and it will most certainly be an extremely large machine.